# Display div based on the selection in a dynamic drop down

Tags: javascript, php, html

All,

I have a drop down where the options are dynamic, based on the Database results. When the user makes a selection from this drop down, I want a div to display the results related to this selection (also pulled from the database, linked to the selection). I have this hybrid html/php/javascript that is neither displaying any errors or doing what I need. My question is, what is wrong here:

```
   $result_stat_query = ("SELECT statid, stat_name FROM stats");

    $result_stat = $DB_con->query($result_stat_query);

if(!$result_stat)
            {
                $DB_con->debug_mode('query', 'error', '#Query Failed<br/>'.$DB_con->error);
                return false;
            }       

echo "<select name='stat_id' onchange='filterContent();'>";

while ($row_stat = $result_stat->fetch()) {

              unset($statid, $stat_name);
              $statid = $row_stat['statid'];
              $stat_name = $row_stat['stat_name']; 
              //declared variables now to set the javascript so that the content only appears for each selected drop down item
              ?>
     <script>
function filterContent() {
var user = document.getElementById("stat_id").value;
var contentA = document.getElementById("contentA");
 if(user=="<?php $statid;  ?>") {
    contentA.style.display="block";
}  
</script>
              <?php
              //now grab each id and stat name and display in the drop down
              echo '<option value="'.$statid.'">'.$stat_name.'</option>';
}

echo "</select>";

?> 

<div id="contentA">
   <?php echo "<p>Stat name= $stat_name</p>";  ?>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried this but it is still not working:
In the head:

```
               <script>
function filterContent() {
var user = document.getElementById("stat_id").value;
var contentA = document.getElementById("contentA");
    contentA.style.display="block";

</script>
```

my php, html part looks like this:

```
  $result_stat_query = ("SELECT statid, stat_name, speed, strength, health, temper, armor, alertness, intelligence, emotion FROM character_stats");

    $result_stat = $DB_con->query($result_stat_query);

if(!$result_stat)
            {
                $DB_con->debug_mode('query', 'error', '#Query Failed<br/>'.$DB_con->error);
                return false;
            }       

echo "<select name='stat_id' onchange='filterContent();'>";

while ($row_stat = $result_stat->fetch()) {

              unset($statid, $stat_name);
              $statid = $row_stat['statid'];
              $stat_name = $row_stat['stat_name']; 
              //declared variables now to set the javascript so that the content only appears for each selected drop down item
              ?>

              <?php
              //now grab each id and stat name and display in the drop down
              echo '<option value="'.$statid.'">'.$stat_name.'</option>';
}

echo "</select>";

?> 

    <div id="contentA">
   <?php echo "<p>Stat name= $stat_name</p>";  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Having the filterContent function within a loop will generate multiple of it. Move this function out of the loop, note that if(user=="<?php $statid;  ?>") will no longer work. You might want to try it out without the if statement.

Comment: Tried that, see my edit. Still not working. The page is displaying the second result from the table in the html which is not right either - should obviously start with the first.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I don't mind pairing with you to get this out of the way. My Skype  ID is sundayguru